# wxWidgets How to turn a panel into a window

Tags: wxwidgets

I want the user to be able to click an existing panel and drag it out of the application to make a separate window they can work in. How can I accomplish this using wxWidgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the built-in way to do this, known as [wxAUI](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/overview_aui.html).

If you absolutely need to do it yourself, you will need to create your own top level window overlapping the panel when it starts to be dragged and then reparent the panel under this window.